# Do dynamic props exist in Svelte 3

Tags: svelte

When I iterate over a dynamic component like:

```
<svelte:component collection={collection} uid={uid} this={upload_component} 
     bind:action={restart}/>
```

Is it possible to use a set of dynamic props for each component. Each component having it's own set of prop names and prop values.

**Solution example:**

```
<script>
    import Info from './Info.svelte';

    const pkgs = [{
        name: 'svelte',
        version: 3,
        speed: 'blazing',
        website: 'https://svelte.dev'
    }, ];
</script>

<Info {...pkgs[0]}/>
```

More in this Rich Harris answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110067/passing-onclick-event-into-dynamically-created-sveltecomponent).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You need [spread props](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/spread-props):

```html
<svelte:component this={upload_component} bind:action={restart} {...someprops}/>
```

(Note that bindings and event listeners are *not* included in those props — but you can always pass down a callback function among your props.)