# Reactivity of dynamic <svelte:component> props

Tags: svelte

My question is similar to this [previous one (do-dynamic-props-exist-in-svelte-3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115156/do-dynamic-props-exist-in-svelte-3). I use spread props as recommended but that does not seem to be working.

Context: I am writing the Conduit RealWorld app with Svelte and my state machine library. I have a component for each route, and each of these components has its own set of props. So I use  as follows:

*RealWorld.svelte*

```js
<script>
  import Home from "./Home.svelte"
  import { routes } from "../constants"

  // Props
  // Common props
  export let dispatch;
  export let user;
  export let route;
  // Home route props
  export let tags;
  export let articles;
  export let page;
  export let activeFeed;
  export let selectedTag;
  export let favoriteStatus;

  const { home, signUp } = routes;

  // Component which will be displayed depending on the route
  const componentRoutes= {
    [home]: Home,
    // [signUp]: Signup
  };
  // Props for the component which will be displayed
  const componentRoutesProps={
    [home]: () => ({tags, articles, page, activeFeed, selectedTag, favoriteStatus})
  };

  $: component = componentRoutes[route]
  $: componentProps = componentRoutesProps[route]()
  $: commonProps = {dispatch, user, route}
  $: console.info(`Realworld`, component.name, componentProps, commonProps, {tags, articles, page, activeFeed, selectedTag, favoriteStatus})
</script>

<svelte:component this="{component}" {...componentProps} {...commonProps} />
```

However, using the previous code leads to loosing reactivity, meaning that the props do change, but the `RealWorld` component does not update.

The same code with:

```html
<svelte:component this="{component}" {tags} {articles} {page} {activeFeed} {selectedTag} {favoriteStatus} {dispatch} {user} {route} />
```

works fine.

I intuit that this may be due to a change in references, and Svelte reacting on the passed references which are later lost somehow in the destructuring? How do you use spread props then? How do I handle my use case?

I can always resort to a simpler `if/then/else` construct, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: It sounds like you've identified a bug. If you can create a much simpler repro illustrating the problem, please [raise an issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues) — thanks

Comment: shoot! did I? Damn, wasn't my intention. Alright, will try to get a repo, I should be able to do that with svelte REPL hopefully, as I do nothing fancy here.

Comment: that may be a reproduction of the possible bug: https://svelte.dev/repl/c30956f32d514063b7694711a3637093?version=3.12.1

Comment: No bug here in the end, cf. my answer. Thanks for the support @RichHarris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Svelte bug here. The issue was that I forgot to add a `$:` before `componentProps` to make it reactive:

```
  // Props for the component which will be displayed
+  $: componentRoutesProps={
+    [home]: {tags, articles, page, activeFeed, selectedTag, favoriteStatus}
  };

  $: component = componentRoutes[route]
  $: componentProps = componentRoutesProps[route]
  $: commonProps = {dispatch, user, route}
  $: console.info(`Realworld`, component.name, componentProps, commonProps, {tags, articles, page, activeFeed, selectedTag, favoriteStatus})
```